# Multiple shema in one field

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Heyho!
Currently I try to add something like a list with multiple fields.

I have a custom field for a person and I wanna add a date and text field to it.
So it's something like this (only for backend):

```
[Person] [Text] [Date]
[Person] [Text] [Date]
[Add More]
```

I was thinking about creating a new shema type but I don't know how to get the "persons select function" or even how to get the date selector..

So yeah, kinda stucked here :)

To get more context: I want to create a callsheets for filming events and I need a list with people, their job and when they have to arrive.

Maybe area is the solution but I havent found a way to say something like "area{person,string,date}" and then always use those types, so the user can't add or remove something.

I hope that's somehow understandable :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `array` field type:

```
addFields: [
 {
   type: 'array',
   name: 'people',
   schema: [
     {
       type: 'string',
       name: 'name'
     },
     {
       type: 'string',
       name: 'job'
     },
     {
       type: 'date',
       name: 'date'
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

Check out the [schema guide](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html) which covers arrays.